# async/await vs ContinueWith

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library, async-await

I was thinking that almost any code using `ContinueWith` can be refactored with `async/await`, but this one is a bit tough. A sketch of what I want to convert:

```
// UI unit testing: close the message box in 1s

Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith((t) => 
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}"); 
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

MessageBox.Show("Hello!");

Debug.Print("continue after a message box");
```

How can it be done with `async/await`?

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: It can't, because you're never really "waiting" for that second to pass. `ContinueWith` is generally an alternative for `async`/`await` on tasks (albeit a much harder one to get right), but the reverse isn't always true.

Comment: @Mario, I showed what I tried, didn't I? It is not like I asked "how to display a message box and send keys to it asynchronously", is it?

Comment: @avo Not that it matters anymore for this question, since you got an accepted answer, but no, you have not shown what you tried. That would involve at least one more code example where you'd show what you tried to solve your own question. [http://whathaveyoutried.com/](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @Mario, understood, I'm learning. What I tried was very close [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21433983/2674222) answer. Do you suggest I should post something that I know beforehand doesn't work?

Comment: @avo Absolutely, you should, because then it may be easier for others to spot a problem with your code and give answers more quickly and maybe it will help others understand even better what you try to accomplish as well. =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can split off the middle part into a helper async method:

```
        private async Task EnterAfterDelay()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        }

        private void MyMethod()
        {
            EnterAfterDelay();
            MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
            Debug.Print("continue after a message box");
        }
```

This reveals a problem with the original code, though, which is that the continuation task is never 'awaited' (given a ContinueWith in the original context), meaning that any exceptions it throws will be unhandled.  Ideally you store it in a Task variable somewhere and decide a good place to await it and handle any exceptions it throws.

---

One quick side note:

With either approach, if the user closes the message box before the second elapses, the {ENTER} will be sent to whatever control has focus after it closes, which may result in unintended actions, such as pressing the default button on whatever window was active before launching the message box.  If the intention is to create a pop-up that goes away automatically, but can be dismissed early, you probably want to just create a custom window that provides the desired behavior.

Comment: Special thanks for the side note, it does make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly your code, but you can do something like this (untested):

```
Func<Action, Task> doAsync = async (action) =>
{
    await Task.Yield();
    action();
};

var messageBoxTask = doAsync(() => 
    MessageBox.Show("Hello!"));

var delay = Task.Delay(1000);
var task = await Task.WhenAny(delay, messageBoxTask);

if (task != messageBoxTask)
{
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
    await messageBoxTask;
}

Debug.Print("continue after a message box");
```

I think it's pretty close.

Comment: This is pretty close, but it does effectively delay the "continue after message box" even if you close the message box before one second elapses.  In practice, this is unlikely to come up, due to human response time limitations.  It would become an issue though if the delay was later increased, as suddenly it reveals that the delay is always enforced, regardless of when the box is closed.

Comment: @DanBryant, agree. How about the updated code? This version also takes care of unneeded `SendKeys.Send` if the message box has been already closed.

Comment: yeah, this is actually slightly better than the OP's code, since it only sends the {ENTER} if the box wasn't actually closed.  There are probably still some possible races with message pumping and when exactly the message box closes (possibly still allowing the {ENTER} to be sent after the message box closes), but they are much less likely in this version.

Comment: @DanBryant, I don't think there's a race condition, because it's just another message loop on the same single UI thread, which pumps one message at a time. I.e., only one of the two tasks may get completed upon each iteration of the message loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract your task out into a method and then await on the method like...

```
Task DelayTask() {
    return Task.Delay(1000);
}


await DelayTask();
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
Debug.Print("continue after a message box");
```

Or you could just write it like...

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
Debug.Print("continue after a message box");
```

Comment: This is not actually equivalent, as in the original code, the message box appears before the 1 second delay elapses.

Comment: `SendKeys.Send` is synchronous. To add to what @DanBryant said, you're doing `SendKeys.Send` to the currently focused control, as there is no message box yet.